# CMAP layout of data

Tags: computational-chemistry

I would like to use the [charmm CMAP](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1367299/) correction in another program (PyRosetta). I have looked at parmfile.doc and io.doc and [this discussion](http://www.charmm.org/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=33451&Searchpage=2&Main=8205&Words=CMAP%20&Search=true#Post33451), but nowhere is it distinctly written how the CMAP is laid out.

For example:

```
PHI1 PHI2 PHI3 PHI4 PSI1 PSI2 PSI3 PSI4 24
!-180
1 2 3 …
```

Is this read as:

```
PHI PSI E
-180 -180 1
-180 -165 2
-180 -150 3
```

Or as:

```
PHI PSI E
-180 -180 1
-165 -180 2
-150 -180 3
```

Also out of curiosity, must the CMAP be defined between two consecutive torsion angles, or can the angles be far apart (topologically)?

PS: This is crossposted from [here](http://www.charmm.org/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=34437#Post34437). And I must say using UBB forums is a pain after getting used to the wonderful SE interface:)

PPS: Would this Q find a better home at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of the [CHARMM forcefield](http://mackerell.umaryland.edu/charmm_ff.shtml) in `par_all36_prot.prm` the comments are a bit more informative:

```
CMAP
! alanine map
C    NH1  CT1  C    NH1  CT1  C    NH1   24
! phi = -180.0
     0.126790      0.768700      0.971260      1.250970      2.121010
     2.720430      2.089440      1.789790
```

So from that it can be inferred that my example is read as

```
PHI PSI E
-180 -180 1
-180 -165 2
-180 -150 3
```